# Function based view models not converting to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have a nested viewmodel setup that need to be expressed as functions due to having to have instances (unless I am missing something). Everything works in the UI, I can nest viewmodels that have nested viewmodels and so on.

However in its current form I get an error

> JavaScript runtime error: Pass a function that returns the value of the ko.computed

when trying to call `ko.toJSON(x);`.

This worked when I had the vms defined without the need for instances however my nesting did not hence the change.

Here is an example of how it is currently.

```
var CityViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable("");
    self.ATMs = ko.observableArray();

    self.AddATM = function () {
        self.ATMs.push(new ATMViewModel);
    }

    self.GetJson = function() {
        alert(ko.toJSON(self)); //Area of interest
    }
}

var ATMViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.PostCode = ko.observable("");
    self.Features = ko.observableArray();

    self.AddFeature = function () {
        self.Features.push(new FeaturesViewModel());
    }
}

var FeaturesViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable("");
    self.Reference = ko.observable("");
}

ko.applyBindings(CityViewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to spot it as well.. a missing `new` keyword

```
ko.applyBindings(new CityViewModel());
//               ====
```

As a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Quango/zf0dLLyr/

I'd recommend Ryan's suggestion for debugging:

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

It was the fact that returned nothing gave me the hint. See 
http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/06/knockout-debugging-strategies-plugin.html

Comment: The very odd thing was I had already made that correction to try and fix it in the actual code. It works given the example so I am setting it as correct... because it is... based on the example here. I will have to see why the real code doesnt function in the same way. Thanks.

Comment: p.s. the pre tip is fantastic!

Comment: Just as an FYI. The reason the example worked but the real code did not was because I had foolishly left a root level with binding to the equivalent of City, which worked when I was using a no instance based vm but obviously is not right for an instance based approach.